# The result size of BN_bn2bin sometimes be 31 instead of 32 on signature->r or signature-s which generate by ECDSA_do_verify

Tags: openssl, ecdsa, sign-in-with-apple

I use openssl to generate a client_secret(JWT) for an Apple token endpoint. I found the post https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123723 which said we should parse R, S value and concatenate these two values.

I use the following code to generate the signature for client_secret:

```
#include <string>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

using namespace std;

class ECDSA256
{
    public:
        ECDSA256(const string& private_key) : is_error_(false), err_str_(""),
        private_key_(NULL), private_key_bio_(NULL), evp_md_ctx_(NULL), ecdsa_sig_(NULL)
        {
            private_key_bio_ = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

            if ((size_t)BIO_write(private_key_bio_, private_key.data(), private_key.size()) != private_key.size())
            {
                is_error_ = true;
                err_str_.append("failed to load private key: BIO_wirte failed\n");
                return;
            }
            
            private_key_ = PEM_read_bio_ECPrivateKey(private_key_bio_, NULL, NULL, NULL);

            if (!private_key_)
            {
                is_error_ = true;
                err_str_.append("failed to load private key: PEM_read_bio_ECPrivateKey failed\n");
                return;
            }

            if (0 == EC_KEY_check_key(private_key_))
            {
                is_error_ = true;
                err_str_.append("failed to load private key: EC_KEY_check_key failed\n");
                return;
            }
        }

        virtual ~ECDSA256()
        {
            clear();
        }

        string sign(const string& data) 
        {
            const string hashed = hash(data);

            if (is_error_)
            {
                return "";
            }

            ecdsa_sig_ = ECDSA_do_sign((const unsigned char*)hashed.data(), hashed.size(), private_key_);

            if (!ecdsa_sig_)
            {
                is_error_ = true;
                err_str_.append("ECDSA_do_sign failed\n");
                return "";
            }

            return bn2raw(ecdsa_sig_->r) + bn2raw(ecdsa_sig_->s);
        }

        void clear()
        {
            if (private_key_bio_)
            {
                BIO_free_all(private_key_bio_);
                private_key_bio_ = NULL;
            }
            if (private_key_)
            {
                EC_KEY_free(private_key_);
                private_key_ = NULL;
            }
            if (evp_md_ctx_)
            {
                EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(evp_md_ctx_);
                evp_md_ctx_ = NULL;
            }
            if (ecdsa_sig_)
            {
                ECDSA_SIG_free(ecdsa_sig_);
                ecdsa_sig_ = NULL;
            }

            is_error_ = false;
            err_str_.clear();
            log_oss_.str("");
        }

        bool is_error()
        {
            return is_error_;
        }

        string err_str()
        {
            return err_str_;
        }

        string log_str()
        {
            return log_oss_.str();
        }

    private:

        bool is_error_;
        string err_str_;
        ostringstream log_oss_;

        EC_KEY* private_key_;
        BIO* private_key_bio_;

        EVP_MD_CTX* evp_md_ctx_;

        ECDSA_SIG* ecdsa_sig_;

        string hash(const string& data)
        {
            evp_md_ctx_ = EVP_MD_CTX_create();

            if (0 == EVP_DigestInit(evp_md_ctx_, EVP_sha256()))
            {
                is_error_ = true;
                err_str_.append("EVP_DigestInit failed\n");
                return "";
            }

            if (0 == EVP_DigestUpdate(evp_md_ctx_, data.data(), data.size()))
            {
                is_error_ = true;
                err_str_.append("EVP_DigestUpdate failed\n");
                return "";
            }

            std::string result;
            
            unsigned int len = 0;

            result.resize(EVP_MD_CTX_size(evp_md_ctx_));

            if (EVP_DigestFinal(evp_md_ctx_, (unsigned char*)result.data(), &len) == 0)
            {
                is_error_ = true;
                err_str_.append("EVP_DigestFinal failed\n");
                return "";
            }

            result.resize(len);

            return result;
        }

        string bn2raw(BIGNUM* bn)
        {
            string result;

            result.resize(BN_num_bytes(bn));
            log_oss_ << "\nresult size: " << result.size();

            BN_bn2bin(bn, (unsigned char*)result.data());

            log_oss_ << "\nresult size: " << result.size();
            log_oss_ << "\nresult char: " << result[0];
            log_oss_ << "\nresult hex : " << BN_bn2hex(bn);

            if (result.size() % 2 == 1 && result[0] == 0x00)
            {
                return result.substr(1);
            }
            log_oss_ << "\nresult size: " << result.size();

            return result;
        }
};
```

Sometimes the signature is invalid. Apple returns `invalid_client`. And I paste the client_secret to jwt.io, jwt.io also said invalid signaure. When the signature is valid, the length of the signature is 63 instead of 64. The log info shows the result size of BN_bn2bin sometimes be 31 instead of 32 on signature->r or signature-s.[image]
[image]

Can anyone give some advice on this situation?

Comment: _When the signature is valid, the length of the signature is 63 instead of 64._ I would expect it the other way around. In this case you would have to pad the too short part (r and/or s) with leading 0x00 values, see [here, chapter 5.2.1 Plain Format](https://www.bsi.bund.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/EN/BSI/Publications/TechGuidelines/TR03111/BSI-TR-03111_V-2-0_pdf.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=2#subsection.5.2.1).

Comment: @Topaco I also met the length of result of BN_bn2bin is 30, Can I padding two leading 0x00 of that result?

Comment: Sure, as described in the linked article r and s are to be padded with leading 0x00 values up to the required length (32 bytes in this case).